# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.url'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.url'
```

Although `six` is already installed:

Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\i\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.11.0)

Comment: do you mean `six.moves.urllib`?

Comment: Do you mean 'six.moves.urllib' ? because I wasn't able to find 'six.moves.url' here : https://pythonhosted.org/six/

Comment: Yes , it should be six.moves.urllib

Thank you